# Troubleshoot a circuit

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have 8 wall sconce lights installed on a circuit, controlled by a dimmer switch. These are the only items on this circuit (20amp). The lights had been working fine until they stopped turning on this weekend. There is power to the dimmer switch, but not to the lights. I've checked the connections at each of the light sconces, and they appear to be fine.

How do I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: “Power to the dimmer switch”, did you test both sides of the switch?  In other words, Is the dimmer bad?

Comment: Try turning the power off at the breaker, replacing the dimmer with just a wirenut, and turning the power back on at the breaker?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sounds like an answer.

Comment: It was the dimmer switch. Thanks for tips, I was way over-thinking this.

Answer (score 1):

### Take the dimmer out of the equation

Try turning off the breaker, removing the dimmer from the circuit, wirenutting the two hot leads that went to the dimmer together, and turning the breaker back on.  If the lights come on, then you need a new dimmer.  If they still don't work, I'd look for a faulty connection somewhere.